# How to hide the Request-Response cycle information from the outputs in ipynb - Spotipy

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, spotipy

I am not sure if it has a common solution for any packages using web API's, but the package I am using is specifically [Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

While I am requesting something from the API (calling any function from the package) it gives a long output of the GET and RESP info first and then gives the desired outputs. Is there a way to hide all the informative outputs as below, when wanted? (like setting some parameters to silent for example)

The output I'd like to hide is something like this;

`headers {' #some info here`

`http status 200`

`GET https://api. ... # GET request link here`

`RESP { ... # a lot of (sometimes undesired) output printed here`

Please let me know if this is an API-specific issue, then I will ask a solution from the git repository.

Comment: If it's an issue with what the API returns, then I'd recommend asking for a solution on GH if you don't find any answers here.

Comment: Could you add an example of this output in an ipynb? (easiest way is probably to use the ipynb support in a public github repo. It sounds like it could be an ipynb-specific issue